# how to set base_url() inside css file using codeigniter, to access background_image_url inside css file?

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I'm using **codeigniter**, I loaded all css files and those are working very well.
My directory structure is
displayed in following image:

[image]

I loaded `style.css`using this code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/style.css">
```

all style attributes are set very well and working. But after that I found images which are set inside css file are not displaying on my site!
My code in css :

```
.social_nav li.facebook a{ background-image:url("images/socials.png"); background-position:0 -30px; background-size:270px 60px}
```

So is their any procedure to set `base_url()` for `background-image:url("images/socials.png"`

Comment: image, inside the assets/css/images or assets/images?

Comment: Have you set the base url `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';` or your domain `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer after getting the help and finally understanding silly mistake of mine everything is working fine except the **adblocker** I **disabled** that and now images are displaying [image]

Answer (score 2):

Since the CSS Background property is relative to the CSS file, you can use:

```
background: url("../../"); /* Becomes the base URL */
```

Now from there you can traverse the path:

```
background: url("../../assets/images/socials.png");
```

You can also use this as alternate:

```
background: url("../images/socials.png");
```

Comment: I added the code explained by you, but its still not working.. background: url("../images/socials.png");

Comment: @AbhijitKumbhar: check your console, i hope u are getting the 404 url for image, please share the url

Comment: after removing back directory code(../) when I checked browser console I found image link  (http://localhost/myproject/assets/css/images/socials.png) on opening this link I found image but its not displaying on my website's index.php page

Comment: @AbhijitKumbhar For the socials, you just leave it how it was.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I never change any code in css that is working in template but when I added the project to codeigniter then it gives me problem but only with this image..

Comment: @AbhijitKumbhar: i suggest to check `background-position:0 -30px;
background-size:270px 60px;` maybe problem here. because links not breaking.. links working fine as per your comment, Praveen, correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @devpro I removed all the 'background-position:0 -30px; background-size:270px ' but it still not displaying

Comment: @AbhijitKumbhar Are you getting any errors in the console? Also please upload the image to imgur and show us how it looks?

Comment: @AbhijitKumbhar: check praveen suggest u, and also test it by using inline css in your html tag `background-image:url("<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/images/socials.png");`

Comment: @devpro Agreed with you man! `:)` Also I strongly feel the image is corrupted.

Comment: where do I set <background-image:url("<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/images/socials.png");>

Comment: @AbhijitKumbhar Don't do anything mate. Just use the relative path. That would be good. Read my answer correctly.

Comment: @PraveenKumar you mean to set php echo in css ??

Comment: @AbhijitKumbhar Don't mix any PHP in CSS mate. Just the `background-image:url("images/socials.png");` should work perfectly.

Comment: @AbhijitKumbhar What do you see in the Console mate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124873/discussion-between-abhijit-kumbhar-and-praveen-kumar).

Answer (score 1):

Note that, if this image `socials.png` is available in `assets/images` folder than you can use like:

```
.social_nav li.facebook a{ 
  background-image:url("../images/socials.png"); //one step back
  background-position:0 -30px; 
  background-size:270px 60px;
}
```

If your image inside the `assets/css/images` than your code must be work, you need to check these two property by changing the values or removing.

```
background-position:0 -30px;
background-size:270px 60px;
```

---

**Side Note:**

*Maybe, in this case, your file is corrupted, also check by using the different image.*

*Also check your browser console, you are getting 404 links for this image if your provided path is wrong.*

Comment: I'm not getting any 404 error in browser , image is avalible at this (localhost/myproject/assets/css/images/socials.png) link but not displaying on my index.php page

Comment: @AbhijitKumbhar: it means, u need to check this `background-position:0 -30px;
background-size:270px 60px;`

Comment: I checked that, also removed that but not working :(

Comment: Is their any option in css to set base url like PHP's base url function "<?php echo base_url(); >?"